# Github pages and custom domain issues

Tags: domains, dns, github

I have used [jekyllbootstrap](http://jekyllbootstrap.com/) to setup my blog at [primux.in](http://primux.in) about 2 weeks ago. The blog has been hosted at github pages at primalpop.github.com. Following the advice from [here](http://pages.github.com/) I have created a CNAME file and pushed it to repository and also added the relevant CNAME records pointing to 207.97.227.245.

Now the problem is that, sometimes the website doesn't load at all from github pages. Most of the times, it loads the index page but every other url is broken. This has been the problem for some time. I initially thought it would take some time for DNS to propagate but it's been nearly 2 weeks now and still most of the urls doesn't work on the website. It has been frustrating to say the least when someone who reads the blog, comes back and say that the link is broken.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you show us an example of the broken link and indicate how they are broken.

Comment: http://primux.in/archive

Answer (score 3):

You have forgotten to set your custom domain value at production_url (see _config.yml).

Comment: After setting the production_url to http://primux.in, it is showing github pages doesn't exist error.

Comment: your CNAME file is wrong. delete `http://`

Comment: Thanks, fixed it. Still primux.in doesn't load from github. :(

Comment: I'm thinking of moving it to custom server.